# Delegate Action does not take 3 arguments

Tags: c#

```
Action showTasks = (String name, String gender, String id) =>
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append("Name: " + name);
            stringBuilder.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            stringBuilder.Append("Gender: " + gender);
            stringBuilder.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
            stringBuilder.Append("Id: " + id);

            var builderGoogle = new AlertDialog.Builder (this);
            builderGoogle.SetTitle ("Logged in");
            builderGoogle.SetMessage (stringBuilder.ToString());
            builderGoogle.SetPositiveButton ("Ok", (o, e) => { });
            builderGoogle.Create().Show();
        };
```

How can I pass 3 input parameters to delegate Action?

Comment: `Action<string, string, string> ....`

Comment: Actually just use var. var showTasks =.... let the compiler deal with the rest.

Comment: @TomTom Nope it won't.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Yes it can, because types are explicitly mentioned, the compiler can infer type from usage.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan What do you mean? How on earth compiler know you mean `Action<T1,T2,T3>` or `SomeOtherAction<T1,T2,T3>` Or `NonGeneric(string, string, string)` delegate? I will agree with you if OP used `new Action<string,string,string>(()=> ...)`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Action<string, string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Remember - there is set of `Action` delegates. All these delegates encapsulate methods which don't return value (i.e. have `void` return type). But void methods have different number of input parameters. Thus there is 17 different `Action` delegates, which encapsulate methods with different number of input parameters (from 0 to 16);

```
Action
Action<T1>
Action<T1,T2>
Action<T1,T2,T3>
...
Action<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8, T9, T10, T11, T12, T13, T14, T15, T16>
```

So, you should pick appropriate delegate

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`Action<T1, T2, T3>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549392%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate:

```
Action<String, String, String> showTasks = (String name, String gender, String id) =>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your type:

```
Action<string, string, string> showTasks = ...
```